# GCP cloud storage: 403-Forbidden while executing `Storage.BucketAccessControls.List` request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to list ACLs for Google cloud storage buckets using the Java client. I am creating the client like this:

```
  // create client
  GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(jsonCredentialsString));

  if(credential.createScopedRequired()) {
    credential = credential.createScoped(StorageScopes.all());
  }

  HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
  JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

  return new Storage.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
      .setApplicationName("app")
      .build();
```

Now using this client I get **200 OK** to execute `Buckets.List` request but I get a **403** error while running the `Storage.BucketAccessControls.List` request.

I am using *service account credentials*. This is the error I get

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Forbidden",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Forbidden"
}
```

What is the correct way to authenticate requests in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is fine. What is causing the 403 are the permissions of your service account. Have a look at how you can [authenticate for Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam) using IAM. *You can also do it on resource level (bucket-by-bucket) to allow for a more granular access.*

Basically, to allow any API call to Storage, you can give it a Storage Admin role. The easiest way to do it is by navigating to Console-IAM & Admin.

Comment: Yeah, I had to provide storage admin permissions to my service account. Even though it already has `project.viewer` permissions, so I was expecting them to apply to storage buckets also. But seems like storage permissions work independently.